# How to select all items which listed in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have list of items inside of recyclerview, and they are multiple selectable.

I want to have select button to select all, and if selected deselect all. I didn't see any option to iterate through RecyclerView.Adapter to do that. How can I implement that?

Thank you.

Comment: u can use a view to depict selected image inside onbindviewholder with if condition to decide whether to show. i.e.when click a button set this boolean true and call notifydatasetchange. it will iterate all the items again and if boolean is set to true then hide not selected image and show selected image in onbindviewholder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to maintain Selected item list and list of items in Adapter,

When you select "Select All" button, just add all item in selected item list and call notifyDataSetChanged

Just a sudo code

```
class adapter {
    ArrayList<Item> selected = new ArrayList<Item>();
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public void selecteAll() {
        selected.clear();
        selected.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clearAll() {
        selected.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void bindView() {
        Item item = items.get(position);

        if(selected.contains(item) {
            // Do selected action
        } else {
           // Non selecetd ctions
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case,

Step - 1 :- first  globally initialize flag in activity class

> **boolean flagSelectAll = false;**

Step - 2 :- Then set below code in Onclick of Button

```
@OnClick(R.id.btnSelectAll)
public void setBtnSelectAll(View view){
    for (int i=0;i<dMyItemLists.size();i++){
        if (dMyItemLists.get(i).isSelected()){
            flagSelectAll = true;
            dMyItemListAdapter.selectAllItem(false);
            dMyItemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else {
            dMyItemListAdapter.selectAllItem(true);
            dMyItemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Step - 3 :- Then create method selectAllItem in recyclerview's adpater class like below **:**

```
public void selectAllItem(boolean isSelectedAll) {
        try {
            if (itemList != null) {
                for (int index = 0; index < itemList.size(); index++) {
                    itemList.get(index).setSelected(isSelectedAll);
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to maintain another list with selected items. You need to create a method to set a flag and in the onBindViewHolder method just check for that flag. Something like this:

```
class MyAdapter(val context: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    val mItems = mutableListOf<ItemObject>()
    private var selectAllItems: Boolean = false

    fun updateList(list: List<ItemObject>) {
        mItems.addAll(list)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun selectAllItems(selectAll: Boolean){
        selectAllItems = selectAll
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val pos = viewHolder.adapterPosition
        viewHolder.checkbox.isSelected = selectAllItems
    }

    class ViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val checkbox: Checkbox = view.myCheckBox
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining a separate list or flag doesn't work for me, as the contents of my recycler view can change at any given moment, and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` can be costly for large data sets. The solution I came up with doesn't use either, instead iterating over the recycler views children. For example, inside whatever function responds to your "select all action", iterate the child views like so:

```
RecyclerView rv = ...;
List<View> selection = ...;
...
public void selectAll() {
    int count = rv.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View view = rv.getChildAt(i);
        if (!view.isActivated()) {
            view.setActivated(true);
            selection.add(view);
        }
    }
}
```